# how to remove on left padding of Tabbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I make a scrollable tab bar in flutter using this code

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        isScrollable: true,
        labelColor: primaryColor,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // to remove bouncing effect on iOS
        tabs: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("Hello"),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("world"),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {}); // just to re render the widget to change the box color
          widget.onTap(index);
        },
      ),
    );
```

and here is the result

[image]

as you can see, there is a lot of space in the left side of my Tab Bar. how to remove that left side padding ?

I think I encounter this issue after updating to Flutter 3.16.4

Comment: Add tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start in TabBar

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use ( tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start )

Here what i fixed with your code below you can see the comments start with **

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            labelColor: primaryColor,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            // labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // ** remove the padding zero
            tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start, // ** Use TabAlignment.start
            automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: false,
            physics:
                const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // to remove bouncing effect on iOS
            tabs: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("Hello"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                  width:
                      20), // **  remove this one because it's count as tab ( so in this case you have 3 tabs)
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("world"),
              ),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(
                  () {}); // just to re render the widget to change the box color
              widget.onTap(index);
            },
          ),
        ),
```